# Which is the best way to 'check if exists` in many to many relationship table in Symfony3?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.3

I have simple implementation of User -> Favourites User Articles:

Controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/articles/{category}/{id}/addtofavorites", name="addToFavourites")
 */
public function addToFavourites($category, $id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $article = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Article")->find($id);
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $user = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:User")->find($user->getId());
    $user->addFavouriteArticle($article);
    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();

    $test = 'true';

    return new JsonResponse($test);
}
```

User Entity:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $firstName;

    /**
     * @var favouriteArticles[]
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Article", cascade={"all"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_favourite_articles",
     *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="article_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
     */
    private $favouriteArticles;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->favouriteArticles = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return favouriteArticles[]
     */
    public function getFavouriteArticles(): array
    {
        return $this->favouriteArticles->toArray();
    }

    /**
     * @param favouriteArticles[] $favouriteArticles
     */
    public function setFavouriteArticles(array $favouriteArticles): void
    {
        $this->favouriteArticles = $favouriteArticles;
    }

    /**
     * Add user
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Article $article
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function addFavouriteArticle(Article $article)
    {
        $this->favouriteArticles[] = $article;

        return $this;
    }
```

So I should change controller method to check if Article already exists in DB and `Favourite button` is clicked again it should remove it from DB (at the moment it just add article every time). How to do it? If it was normal table I would add in User Repository, like this:

```
return (boolean)$this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->andWhere('u.article = :article')
            ->setParameter('article', $rticle)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult();
```

But in this case with ManyToMany relation I don't know how and where to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public function addFavouriteArticle(Article $article)
{
    if ($this->favouriteArticles->contains($article)) {
        return;
    }

    $article->setUser($this);
    $this->favouriteArticles[] = $article;
}

public function removeFavouriteArticle(Article $article)
{
    $this->favouriteArticles->removeElement($article);
}
```

This way user would never add same article to his favourites (because it aleady exists).

Comment: But the point is when he click favourite button again to add / remove article, every time when he click the Favourite button.

Comment: my bad, my code will return error if I tried to add same Article.  Your code works fine, but there is no check if article exists. I want to remove it from table if user don't want to have it in Favourties. And next to add it again if he want to have it again.

Comment: Okay, if I change if statement to `if ($this->favouriteArticles->contains($article)) `{`
            `$this->removeFavouriteArticle($article);`
            `return;`
        `}`
it works fine, but how to return different response for add / remove to show to user ?

Comment: Hmm you are confused, or i am :) Do you want to remove Article form DB, or relation of that article to user?

Answer (score 0):

Mr [Zorpen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1784871/zorpen) wrote everything correctly, but I would have done a little differently. In my case, the method for checking "if exists" is separately from the addition. Plus, there is a check for the emptiness of the article.

```
/**
 * @param Article $article
 * @return bool
 */
public function isContainsArticle(Article $article)
{
    if ($this->favouriteArticles->contains($article)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * @param Article $article
 * @return bool
 */
public function addArticle (Article $article)
{
    if (empty($article) || $this->isContainsArticle($article)) {
        return false;
    }
    $this->favouriteArticles->add($article);

    return true;
}

/**
 * @param Article $article
 */
public function removeArticle (Article $article)
{
    $this->favouriteArticles->removeElement($article);
}
```

Comment: Thank your for you response, still I don't have 15 rep to to upvote you, but I will comeback when I reach it. Also in your code there is no remove method.

Comment: Looks fine, but how can I return different response for add / remove article ? Which to show in twig file later.

Comment: @Daniel Pysarenko What does `empty($article)` mean? it could not be empty ever. If you don't pass it, it will throw an error, if you do pass it it's not an array to check it for emptiness.

Comment: Look, if you want to add an article there are two ways: 1 - this article is exists in arrayCollection and it return false, 2 - this article doesn`t exist in arrayCollection and it return true. Next you can transfer to this bool to a twig and make checking. If you keep in mind retun something like 'added' or '1' when you added and 'removed' or '2' when you deleted, it is better use 'isContainsArticle' method and if it returns true -> remove or if it returns false -> add. I can explain you in Russian, if you want.

Comment: @DanielPysarenko Thank you !

Comment: @Zorpen, anything can happen! the Article can be empty, becouse it can be like 'NULL', 'FALSE', '0', 0, '' etc... about empty() explains well here http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php (EN) http://php.net/manual/ru/function.empty.php (RU)

Comment: @Daniel Pysarenko I know that empty is a function. What i mean is that it doesn't check if OBJECT is empty. A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE.

Comment: @Zorpen, as well as NULL, which object can be. And object is a variable, so empty() can check objects, for example, if you want to get UserEntity object via EntityManager, it can return null, and empty copes well with checking it out.

Comment: @Daniel Pysarenko No it can't. Check this example `<?php class Something {} $something = new Something(); die(var_dump(empty($something)));` it will print `bool(false)`. Situation that you are describing is something different if you try to fetch User object from EntityManager and it doesn't exist sure it will return NULL, but that NULL is just a value returned by EntityManager and it's not an object.